# The on click function is not working on first click

Tags: jquery

I hide sub menu by default for mobile view and implement toggle, only show sub menu after Click on title.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(window).width() <= 639) {
      $('.footer-widgets .footer-widget').each(function(e, elm) {
        var ac = $(this).find('.widget-title');
        $(ac).next('div').addClass('closed');
        $(ac).on('click', function(a) {
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
          $(this).next('div').toggleClass('closed');
          $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
          $(elm).siblings().find('.widget-title').next('div').addClass('closed');
          $(elm).siblings().find('.widget-title').next('div').slideUp();

        });
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-widgets d-lg-flex">
  <div class="footer-widget footer-widget-3">
    <div id="nav_menu-1" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
      <span class="gamma widget-title">Contact</span>
      <div class="menu-footer-section-3-container closed">
        <ul id="menu-footer-section-3" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1628" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1628">
            <a href="/Contact/">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-widget footer-widget-4">
    <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
      <span class="gamma widget-title">Resources</span>
      <div class="menu-footer-section-4-container closed">
        <ul id="menu-footer-section-4" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1792" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1792">
            <a href="/blogs/">Blogs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css Code

```
.footer-widgets .footer-widget .closed {
    display: none;
}
```

In my code - The onclick function is not working on first time click.

See here - https://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/ye2qL0ta/1/

Comment: How long do you wait for your first click? Are you sure the document load has fully executed already when you first click?

Comment: @dpDesignz check here - https://jsfiddle.net/vikastyagi87/ye2qL0ta/1/

Comment: Is your content dependant on the active class? Are you able to post an example of what you expect the finished code to look like when it's clicked open and when it's clicked closed? I think at the moment your code is getting confused with the toggle class and slide features.

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        if ($(window).width() <= 639) {
            $('.footer-widgets .footer-widget').each(function (e, elm) {
                $('.widget_nav_menu .closed').css('display', 'none');
                var ac = $(this).find('.widget-title');
                $(ac).on('click', function (a) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                    $(this).next('div').addClass('closed');
                    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
                    $(elm).siblings().find('.widget-title').next('div').addClass('closed');
                    $(elm).siblings().find('.widget-title').next('div').slideUp();

                });
            });
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="footer-widgets d-lg-flex">
  <div class="footer-widget footer-widget-3">
    <div id="nav_menu-1" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
      <span class="gamma widget-title">Contact</span>
      <div class="menu-footer-section-3-container closed">
        <ul id="menu-footer-section-3" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1628" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1628">
            <a href="/Contact/">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-widget footer-widget-4">
    <div id="nav_menu-5" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
      <span class="gamma widget-title">Resources</span>
      <div class="menu-footer-section-4-container closed">
        <ul id="menu-footer-section-4" class="menu">
          <li id="menu-item-1792" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-1792">
            <a href="/blogs/">Blogs</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```